# Developing chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser-extension

I  am a beginner in developing chrome extensions , i have written the following code in **popup.html** file which i linked to `default_popup` of `browser_action` of my extension

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script  type="text/javascript" >
  function returnname()
  {
        var x=document.getElementById("name").value;

        alert(x);
  };
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <p>Username : <input type="text"  id="name" height="20" width="50" />
  </p>
  <p>Password : <input type="password"  id="password" height="20" width="50" />
  </p>

  <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="returnname()" value="login"></input>
  <textarea id="return_name" rows="2" columns="20"></textarea>

  </body>
  </html>
```

But whenever i  click login button javascript is not running as in ,it's not displaying any alert message . what have i missed here?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to bind your codes, and avoid using onclick on your chrome extensions as it wont work anymore on the latest chrome version.

using addEventListener or if you use jQuery. use the click there

```
$().click(function(){

});
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#inline-code-considered-harmful